# Searching for a specific last character in a string

Tags: objective-c

I would like to search for a specific last character in a NSString and couldn't figure out a way. In C# for example, I can do lastindexof to get the index of the char I'm searching for and then use substring to get what I want. Is there a way in Obj C to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *s = @"aabbcc";
[s rangeOfString:@"b" options:NSBackwardsSearch]; // {3, 1}
```

Comment: I just need to search for a specific last character in a string and do some validations if found.

Comment: This is exactly it, you just get a NSRange object in response, of which you are only interested in index (3)

Comment: What does this mean? {3,1}

Comment: Look up the method doc and what nsrange is, 3 is a starting position, 1 is length, this is how Cocoa operates on strings